# Making Report From Four Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am working in Oracle APEX.I am Making report from following four tables `Patient History Junction and Disease` but unable to make it.

I want to `SELECT`

> Pat_Name,Pat_Age` from Patient Table

.

> Treated_By,Sys_Date from History Table

and

> Dis_Name from Disease Table

.There is a `Junction` Table between `History and Disease`. Below is the diagram of the above scenario.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` each of the tables, similar to this:

```
select p.pat_name,
  p.pat_age,
  h.treated_by,
  h.sys_date,
  d.dis_name
from patient p
inner join history h
  on p.pat_id = h.pat_id
  and p.app_id = h.app_id
left join junction j
  on p.pat_id = j.pat_id
left join disease d
  on j.dis_id = d.dis_id
```

If you need help learning join syntax, check this helpful [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Notice that I used an `INNER JOIN` between `patient` and `history` and joined the tables on both keys in `patient`. This type of join will return all matching records in both tables.

I used a `LEFT JOIN` on the other two tables which will return all of the patient/history data even if there is not a matching record in the other two tables. Depending on your need, you might be able to use an `INNER JOIN` on those tables.